# Carousel layout in Flutter

Tags: flutter

how can I make the carousel layout view pager in a flutter with auto-increment like image slider, like in android we use view pager for this to scroll automatically.

Comment: use pageview, and for auto scroll use countdown package

Answer (score 0):

use

> ListView ([source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html))

```dart
ListView(
  // This next line does the trick.
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image]